# How I deal with this localization error on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, security

So, this is happening both on my smartphone when I search for 'malwarebytes', and on my PC when I search for 'xbox'.

[The first result of my search on the word 'xbox' on my PC. It shows a list of results for the Xbox page with 'Sem título' (translated from Portuguese to 'No title') on each item of the list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INgTz.png)

This error occurs at random everytime I reload the page. Sometimes it loads like in the image, sometimes it doesn't.

Does anyone have any idea what this is and how I can deal with it?

There is no alert from my antivirus, clearing navigation data doesn't solve it. Haven't tried reinstalling Chrome. Restarting the computer doesn't fix it.